# Hibernate ManyToOne/N+1 Issue

Tags: hibernate

I have a persistent class that contains ManyToOne relationships with my user table for auditing purposes. In fact, all of my classes have these fields, even the User class.

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable {

@Fetch(value=FetchMode.SELECT)
@ManyToOne(optional=false, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
@JoinColumn(name = "CREATE_USER_ID")
public User getCreatedBy() {
    return createdBy;
}

@Fetch(value=FetchMode.SELECT)
@ManyToOne(optional=false)
@NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
public User getLastUpdatedBy() {
    return lastUpdatedBy;
}
}
```

Just to make this even better, some maroon made the auditing fields in most of the tables a CHAR(8), but the field in T_USER a VARCHAR2(8), meaning that a foreign key can't be created on them.

Anyhoo, a query for MyClass will kick off queries to populate the audit fields, which then in turn kicks off a query to populate the User's audit field.

I rarely need the audit fields, so I want to make them lazy. Unfortunately, I think I have alot working against me here, not least of which is a poorly designed schema.

Can anyone help me out here?

Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the @Fetch(value=FetchMode.SELECT) annotation and the @ManyToOne(optional=false, fetch=FetchType.LAZY) would be fighting against one another, have you tried removing the @Fetch(value=FetchMode.SELECT) for each entity and adding fetch=FetchType.LAZY to both of the associations?

Another reason may be that the @NotFound annotation is fighting against the optional=false annotation parameter.  One says that there can be a NULL where the other says there can't.  I believe that in a case where you can have a null value in a *toOne association, you cannot have lazy loading unless the association cannot be NULL.

Comment: Tried it with no luck. I was making the assumption that the lack of Foreign Keys was hurting my ability to lazy load the ManyToOne relationships.

Comment: Ok, I Updated my answer with another suggestion.

Comment: I accepted your answer. On further research, it looks like the NotFound is kicking off the additional query. I'd love to have the best of both worlds where a ManyToOne could be null, but the NotFound wouldn't kick off the additional query.